# can't get value from spinner getter

Tags: java, android, spinner

I want to save selected values from 3 spinners into variables with getter/setter. But when i trying to show values it's return nothing.

Here is set methods

```
    spinner_value(spinner, spinner1_selected);
    setLang(getSpinner(spinner1_selected));

    spinner_value(spinner2, spinner2_selected);
    setCountry(getSpinner(spinner2_selected));

    spinner_value(spinner3, spinner3_selected);
    setCity(getSpinner(spinner3_selected));
```

Trying to show any value

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setTitle(getLang())
    .setMessage(getCountry())
     .show();
```

My spinner to variable converter

```
public void spinner_value(Spinner spinner, final String spinner_value)
{
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
            Object item = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);
            setSpinner(item.toString(), spinner_value);
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });

}
```

My getter\setter

```
public void setSpinner(String input, String spinner) {
    spinner = input;
}
public String getSpinner(String spinner) {
    return spinner;
}
```

Comment: Your getter is simply returning the string that they inputted. If I used `getSpinner("foo")` your getter would return "Foo" back to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

usually You get the values (in Your case You want to have a String) like this:

```
       String text = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

But I really don´t know what You want to do. Your get/set methods are just returning or changing String values that  You give. SetSpinner sets only both given values equal. getSpinner just returns the same String You give, that doesn´t make sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve you problem.**

**main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spnLanguage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/language"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spnCountry"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/country"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>


    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spnCity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/city"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnValue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Value"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**string.xml**

```
<string-array name="language">
   <item>"Language 1"</item>
   <item>"Language 2"</item>
   <item>"Language 3"</item>
   <item>"Language 4"</item>
   <item>"Language 5"</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="country">
   <item>"Country 1"</item>
   <item>"Country 2"</item>
   <item>"Country 3"</item>
   <item>"Country 4"</item>
   <item>"Country 5"</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="city">
   <item>"City 1"</item>
   <item>"City 2"</item>
   <item>"City 3"</item>
   <item>"City 4"</item>
   <item>"City 5"</item>
</string-array>
```

**MyActivity.java**

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private Spinner spnLanguage;
    private Spinner spnCountry;
    private Spinner spnCity;
    private Button btnValue;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        btnValue = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnValue);
        spnLanguage = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnLanguage);
        spnCountry = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnCountry);
        spnCity = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnCity);


        btnValue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this)
                        .setTitle(spnLanguage.getSelectedItem().toString())
                        .setMessage(spnCountry.getSelectedItem().toString() +" "+spnCity.getSelectedItem().toString())
                        .show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```